# Cross origin resource sharing with tomcat sever

Tags: tomcat, cross-domain, cors

I would like to allow cross origin requests to my server.
I found the following filter code:

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
  // For security reasons set this regex to an appropriate value
  // example: ".*example\\.com"
  private static final String ALLOWED_DOMAINS_REGEXP = ".*";

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
      ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");

    if (origin != null && origin.matches(ALLOWED_DOMAINS_REGEXP)) {
          System.out.println("CorsFilter:: origin matches, yey");
      resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);

      if ("options".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {

        resp.setHeader("Allow", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS");
        if (origin != null) {
          String headers = req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
          String method = req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method");
          resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", method);
          resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers);
          resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        }
        resp.getWriter().flush();
        return;
      }
    }

    // Fix ios6 caching post requests
    if ("post".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {
      resp.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    }

    if (filterChain != null) {
      filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
  }

  @Override public void destroy() {}
  @Override public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}
}
```

It seems that it does anything only if there is first an OPTIONS request. However, in my case i don't see any OPTIONS request, but only a GET request. Am i missing anything? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Tomcat 7.0.41, you can control CORS behavior via a [built-in filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter).

Pretty much the only thing you have to do is edit the global web.xml in CATALINA_HOME/conf and add the filter definition:

```
     <!-- ================== Built In Filter Definitions ===================== -->

      ...

     <filter>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
     </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>

    <!-- ==================== Built In Filter Mappings ====================== -->
```